# How can equations be written more quickly?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Usually I write equations in questions/answers, but writing the equation in LaTeX takes up the most time. It takes me nearly three or four times as long to write them in LaTeX. Is there any way to make my equation writing faster? I already use a visual LaTeX editor to speed things up, but I'm wondering if there are other things I can try. Maybe a program that can convert common equations that are written down into LaTeX, kind of like OCR but from math into a language? (I'm not hopeful that there's anything like that, though).

Comment: Here is a somewhat similar past question: [What is the fastest way to type math equations at stackexchange?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6750/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-type-math-equations-at-stackexchange). You can also have a look at the post tagged [mathjax+editor](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax+editor) to see what programs other users use. This question is somewhat related, too: [Bookmarklet plugin to speed up LaTeX macro typing](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16802/bookmarklet-plugin-to-speed-up-latex-macro-typing).

Comment: I do with a) practice, b) copy/paste, and c) I type fast, almost as fast as I can think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For beginers, I think mathquill (http://mathquill.com) is very helpful in a sense that it is intuitive to input divisions, function commands like sin max etc. And you can move cursor around to subscript, superscript by using arrow keys.  After you have done editing, copy the TeX it generates, and paste in your post editor.

Answer (score 4):

Writing LaTeX fast is mostly a matter of habit. The more you use it, the faster you type. On StackExchange, you can even get quicker because you can edit the question (or other answers), crop the LaTeX code, paste and arrange it according to your needs.

However, you can use an online LaTeX editor, with buttons, like [latex4technics](https://www.latex4technics.com/).